# WordPress add user role with $ultimatemember

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress user like this :

```
$userdata = array(
        'user_login' =>  $login,
        'user_pass'  =>  $pass,
        'user_email' => $mail,
    );
    $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
```

and I want to add a user role using Ultimate Member like this :

```
 global $ultimatemember;
    um_fetch_user($user_id);
    $ultimatemember->user->set_role('role-slug');
```

But when I do it like this, I have an error

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function set_role() on null
```

I've tried before with a row 'role' => 'role_slug' in the userdata but it doesn't work :(

Comment: What return this function `um_fetch_user`?

Comment: This function set the current ultimate member user with the id in param, so you can work on a specific user

Comment: This does require that you have installed the plugin `ultimatemember` though. Have you?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this help you

```
$userdata = array(
        'user_login' =>  $login,
        'user_pass'  =>  $pass,
        'user_email' => $mail,
    );
$user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);


$wp_user_object = new WP_User($user_id );
$wp_user_object->set_role('editor');
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is basically like this:
https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/32-change-user-community-role

Which is correct, *if you have installed the ultimatemember plugin*

---

It might be failing because the provided `$user_id` is not a valid user-id.

`wp_insert_user` will return either `int` (id for the user) or `WP_Error`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/

Read up on `WP_Error`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_error/

---

**If `wp_insert_user` returns an error, there could be many causes:**

- Passing invalid email address.
- Email address is allready taken by a different user.
- Other plugins have added restrictions on password strength, *or any other requirement*.

---

With `filter_var` we can check if the email is valid:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

And with `is_wp_error` we can check if `wp_insert_user` returns a `WP_Error`:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_wp_error/

**With these functions, we can find and avoid the issue:**

```php
// check if email is valid
if( false === filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ){
    echo 'The email is invalid';
    return;
}


$userdata = [
    'user_login' =>  $login,
    'user_pass'  =>  $pass,
    'user_email' =>  $mail,
];

$user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);

// check if error occurred
if( is_wp_error($user_id) ){
    echo $user_id->get_error_message(); // <-- this should reveal the cause of the issue
    return; 
}



global $ultimatemember;
um_fetch_user($user_id);

$ultimatemember->user->set_role('role-slug');
```